# Function is not returning the control of the program at the expected location

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have this code snippet here

```
if(isset($c) && isset($d)) 
{
echo $qry2;
retrieve(mysqli_query($qry1)) || die(mysqli_error());
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
retrieve(mysqli_query($qry2)) || die(mysqli_error()) ;
}
```

When the condition is true then only the first retrieve() function is being called, I had this concept that the control of a program returns to the next line from where the function is being called, this is in general w.r.t to any programming language but here this is not the case, when I `echo $qry2`, I get the desired result i.e. the query is being built properly, the reason I added `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` was to check if there are any errors which are not being displayed, any ideas on how to achieve passing both the parameters to `retrieve()` from within the if block? If I move the function call which contains $qry2 before the part which contains $qry1, then only qry2 is being displayed.

Comment: Does `retrieve` return a truthy value?

Comment: retrieve() is a function of type void, it is not returning any value, my question is where will be the control of program transferred when retrieve has been executed?

Comment: Well there you go, that's your problem. If `retrieve` doesn't return anything, `|| die(...)` takes effect.

Comment: so if I make retrieve return 0 or something and store it in a variable then the second retrieve() call will be attended?

Comment: `0` is falsy. It needs to return a truthy value. The best one would be `true`, but then it makes no sense to have `|| die()`. Just remove the `|| die(...)` part, or restructure your code to make sense :p

Comment: Restructuring it is then. Thanks. Chose your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said in your question, I can only assume that `retrieve` is not returning a truthy value. Of course, without seeing what `retrieve` is, it's impossible to say for certain. However I would hazard a guess that it loops through the result set and builds an array of rows, which it then returns.

If the query returns no rows, then `retrieve` might just return an empty array, which is a falsy value. This causes the script to `die(mysqli_error())`, but since there was no error in the query the result is essentially `die("")`.

Comment: Absolutely retrieve displays all the results being returned by the query, the thing is that only the first call to retrieve is being attended to from with in the block? Suppose retrieve ran successfully then which line of the program will be executed next?

Comment: If `retrieve` doesn't return a truthy value, `|| die()` will be called, ending your script immediately.

Comment: I guess I will provide a default value for one of the arguments of retrieve and if it is not default then via recursion will call retrieve again.